# Extra margin on side of an image in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, webkit

```
<div>
  <img src ='image.png'  style="display: block" />
</div>
```

In Chrome, this renders a 1px margin on right side of the image and pushes wrapper div out. How to remove the margin?

Answer (score 2):

Use the margin and padding in the style attribute as shown below:

```
<div>
  <img src ='image.png' style="display: block; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" />
</div>
```

In addition to this, you can also remove the border by adding the style `"border:0px"`.

I have not tried it, let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS to remove only that will still make your website look different in other browsers. It's best to use a CSS reset to get the same formatting in all browsers.

CSS reset like this:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

I saw this behavior in Safari as well. Try this.

```
<div class="group-holder" style="display: table;">
  <img src="myimage1.gif" style="display: table-cell;" />
  <img src="myimage1.gif" style="display: table-cell;" />
  <img src="myimage1.gif" style="display: table-cell;" />
</div>
```

This worked for me.